# Query Not Showing Certain Positive Values

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm attempting to import some data to my Google Sheet.

Using `QUERY` to reshape my data, an example code of what I am trying to import is as follows:

```
=query(importhtml("http://statfox.com/cbb/cbbteam.asp?teamid=DUKE&season=2019&log=1",
 "table",8),"Select * where Col2 is not null order by Col1")
```

Unfortunately, in many cases where a team is an underdog and the line should be +#, the query is not returning the value.

If I remove the `QUERY` and use the following `importhtml` all values show up correctly:

```
=importhtml("http://statfox.com/cbb/cbbteam.asp?teamid=DUKE&season=2019&log=1","table",8)
```

Any insight into the matter or ideas on what might be causing this or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

this is because imported data are in the format `+2.5` instead of simple `2.5`

the solution is to remove **+** sign with:

```
=QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(
 IMPORTHTML("http://statfox.com/cbb/cbbteam.asp?teamid=DUKE&season=2019&log=1", "TABLE", 8),
 "+", "")), "Select * where Col2 is not null order by Col1")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much - this is exactly what I needed!